# Converting time format in swift.

Tags: ios, swift

i have come across to a time format such as this .

2017-09-27T17:25:01+08:00

Anyone knows what this time means? and how do i compare this to the current time to calculate the amount of time that is left or exceeded?

Comment: its the `UTC offset` It is generally shown in the format `±[hh]:[mm], ±[hh][mm], or ±[hh]`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik ok, but how do i convert this in swift to a normal time?

Answer (score 2):

It's the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
let isoDate = "2017-09-27T17:25:01+08:00"
let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
let myDate: Date? = dateFormatter.date(from: isoDate)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there anyway i can ignore the +08:00.. Cuz i want the 17:25:01.. but after the formatting, the time becomes weird.

Comment: @progammingBeignner in order to get a string representation using your local time zone `myDate!.description(with: .current)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to convert the String to Date in Swift:

```
let dateStr = "2017-09-27T17:25:01+08:00"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"
dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func dateFormatter(strDate: String, format: String? = "yyyy-MM-dd") -> String {
        // create dateFormatter with local time format
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.local
        let date = dateFormatter.date(from: strDate)// create date from string

        // change to a readable time format
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        let timeStamp = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)

        return timeStamp
    }
```

Try this above code for converting time format.